# Matrix Chain Multiplication using Dynamic Programming in C++ Program Crashes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have written following C++ program to implement to implement MCM using Dynamic Programming. But the following program crashes. What is wrong in my code ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#define SZ 10
using namespace std;

int table[SZ][SZ];
int P[] = {2,3,3,5};

int MCM(int i, int j)
{
    if(i==j) return 0;

    else
    {
        int min = INT_MAX;

        for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
        {
            if(table[i][k]==0)
                table[i][k] = MCM(i,k);
            if(table[k+1][j]==0)
                table[k+1][j] = MCM(k+1,j);
            int sum = table[i][k] + table[k+1][j] + P[i-1]*P[j]*P[k];
            if(sum<min)
                min = sum;  
        }
        return min;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = sizeof(P)/sizeof(P[0]);
    printf("Minimum number of mutiplications is %d",MCM(0,size-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there any error messages displayed?

Comment: @BobJarvis No program just crashes.

Comment: It is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I got what is wrong with this its just a minor mistake

The loop on should on line 17 should end at the condition

```
k<j
```

and not at

```
k<=j
```

The program compiles and runs successfully

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#define SZ 10
using namespace std;

int table[SZ][SZ];
int P[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3};

int MCM(int i, int j)
{
    if(i==j) return 0;

    else
    {
        int min = INT_MAX;

        for(int k=i;k<j;k++) // bug was here: for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
        {
            if(table[i][k]==0)
                table[i][k] = MCM(i,k);
            if(table[k+1][j]==0)
                table[k+1][j] = MCM(k+1,j);
            int sum = table[i][k] + table[k+1][j] + P[i-1]*P[j]*P[k];
            if(sum<min)
                min = sum;  
        }
        return min;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = sizeof(P)/sizeof(P[0]);
    printf("Minimum number of mutiplications is %d",MCM(1,size-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is going to infinite loop. Besides you have made some mistakes:

1. You have never assigned the optimum value in the table (when you find minimum sum, you are not storing it). Hence every time you are checking for table[i][j] == 0, it's true
2. k in your loop can be equal to j and you are using k+1, this is a mistake

Anyway I think the right version of your code should be something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#define SZ 10
using namespace std;

int table[SZ][SZ];
int P[] = {1,2,3,4};

int MCM(int i, int j)
{
    if(i==j) return 0;

    else
    {
        int min = INT_MAX;

        for(int k=i;k<j;k++)
        {
            if(table[i][k]==0)
                table[i][k] = MCM(i,k);
            if(table[k+1][j]==0)
                table[k+1][j] = MCM(k+1,j);
            int sum = table[i][k] + table[k+1][j] + P[i]*P[j]*P[k];
            if(sum<min)
                min = sum;
       }
       table[i][j] = min;
       return min;
   }
```

}

```
int main()
{
    int size = sizeof(P)/sizeof(P[0]);
    printf("Minimum number of mutiplications is %d",MCM(0,size-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time MCM(0, size-1) is called, the parameter i = 0, but then you subtract 1 and use the resulting -1 to access P[-1] (on line 23).  That probably causes the crash.

Comment: After fixing that also program crashes, I think something is wrong with the parameters to the function but i am not able to figure it out.